# My differential equation solver not solving the differential equation

Tags: python-3.x, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve ODE using euler method 1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). But my code isn't solving anything. The code is very similar to my teacher, to the point that I can't find any significant difference. Can anybody help?

```
enter from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def funkce(y, t):
 return(-y)

def euler_1(dt, y, t, funkce ):
 y = y + dt * funkce(y, t)
 t = t + dt
 return (y,t)

def solver(y0, t0, tstop, dt, typ):
 y = y0
 t = t0
 ys = [y]
 ts = [t]
while (t < tstop):
   (y,t) = typ(dt, y, t, funkce)
   ts.append(t)
   ys.append(y)
 return(ys,ts) 

plt.plot(solver(1, 0, 50, 0.05, euler_1))
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
y = np.exp(-t)
plt.plot(t, y)

plt.show()
```

Note: the last plot is to compare to the analytical solution.
You can find the plot output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6cff.png).
When I retun from solver y and t instead of ys,ts it just show the last line of ys and ts.

Any help apreciated.

Comment: The order of arguments in the return is wrong and you need to to unpack the result from your function call: `plt.plot(*solver(1, 0, 50, 0.05, euler_1))`

Comment: Yess that did the trick, thank you!